# matplotlib.pyplot: set distance for axis units

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1))
plt.show()
```

shows
[image]

But if I set unit to 0.5:
`plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 0.5))` shows
[image]

x-axis is hardly readable.

Is there a way to set distance for every x-axis unit so it could extend the plot automatically (on x direction)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than controlling the size of the figure itself...

Comment: @lrnzcig but simply scaling image doesn't help either.

Comment: I think so... you just got an answer that does exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Operating on size of the figure does the job. Play with it, find your desired size/ratio etc.